# What's the OSX equivalent of AS3s ExternalInterface

Tags: objective-c, macos, actionscript-3

AS3 has a method named [ExternalInterface](http://scriptcult.com/subcategory_155/article_334-call-javascript-function-from-as-and-viceversa.htm) that allows an external process to call methods in a running as3 app and visa versa.

I'd like to accomplish the same thing with OSX. I'm pretty new to OSX and am unsure of what's available / what my options are.

What would be the best way to pass runtime parameters to an OSX app and return a result to the calling routine (python script, JS, .app or whatever)

Comment: 1. ExternalInterface is not a method but a full API. 2. Nothing to do with external process either, it can be used between a swf and whatever contains it. Finally 3. What you want to do is not even related in any ways to what ExternalInterface does.

Comment: 1)Excuse my poor use of terminology. 2) By external I meant something that is not the app itself. 3) I dont understand why you would this. ExternalInterface provides for passing arguments during runtime does it not? Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

When running Flash Player in the browser `ExternalInterface` will only interact with Javascript in the container HTML page. This works about the same across OS and browser.

When running AS3 in AIR, `ExternalInterface` doesn't communicate with the OS. To interact with the OS from AIR you can use [`NativeProcess`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/desktop/NativeProcess.html) to invoke command line actions.